# search in multi table width different columen

Tags: php, mysql

hello i have three table for save book by type .

```
table_rmance : 
name_ro    date
 book1   123424
 book2   123444
 book3   234323


table_history :
 name_hi    date
 book1   445424
 book2   223444
 book3   453323

table_fantasy :
 name_fa    date
 book1   199924
 book2   183444
 book3   334323
```

i want when users search . find key in three table and sho result by date Desc . i use UNION  and Join but return . any suggestion way?

```
$requerst = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM `table_rmance`) UNION (SELECT * FROM `table_fantasy`) ORDER BY `date` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

return : The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

update #1 : 'id' auto incripment exist in three table .

update #2 : user search 'book1' ank result like this :

```
#1 book1 from table_history
#2 book1 from table_fantasy
#3 book1 from table_rmance
```

Comment: where the key in tables?

Comment: can you provide an example of what the user might search, and the structure of the results you're expecting/wanting?

Comment: Specify the column names you want to return (do not use SELECT *) and then give an alias name to the columns which is the same.